# Do all commercial ionizers produce harmful ozone?

Tags: human-biology

I'm not a scientist. I have read that negative ions have health benefits. I am interested in increasing the ratio of negative to positive ions in the air in my home.

I see that ionizer machines exist (e.g. https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=ionizer).

I have also read that such ionizers produce ozone and that ozone can damage the lungs. Also sorry for not knowing what tags to use.

Do all ionizer machines produce ozone and are the levels produced harmful?

Please forgive me for my ignorance. If this is the wrong place to ask this question then please help me to find the right place.

Comment: "Negative ions" in this context having health benefits is complete nonsense pseudoscience.

Comment: This seems more to be about the specifications of a commercial product or set of products rather than a specific biology question. To be on-topic, you'd need to ask about ozone concentrations that would be harmful - to perhaps specified tissues of a particular set of creatures - and you'd need to show your research. Finding out if such levels are produced by a commercial machine would be off-topic here.